# Python : How to create a flat dictionary from a nested dictionary that is indexed using a tuple?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a nested dictionary as follows:

```
{(1, 1): {'Transportation_Cost': 4},
 (1, 2): {'Transportation_Cost': 5},
 (1, 3): {'Transportation_Cost': 6},
 (1, 4): {'Transportation_Cost': 8},
 (1, 5): {'Transportation_Cost': 10},
 (2, 1): {'Transportation_Cost': 6},
 (2, 2): {'Transportation_Cost': 4},
 (2, 3): {'Transportation_Cost': 3},
 (2, 4): {'Transportation_Cost': 5},
 (2, 5): {'Transportation_Cost': 8},
 (3, 1): {'Transportation_Cost': 9},
 (3, 2): {'Transportation_Cost': 7},
 (3, 3): {'Transportation_Cost': 4},
 (3, 4): {'Transportation_Cost': 2},
 (3, 5): {'Transportation_Cost': 4}}
```

I'd like to convert this into a flat dictionary that looks like this:

```
{(1, 1): 4,
 (1, 2): 5,
 (1, 3): 6,
 (1, 4): 8,
 (1, 5): 10,
 (2, 1): 6,
 (2, 2): 4,
 (2, 3): 3,
 (2, 4): 5,
 (2, 5): 8,
 (3, 1): 9,
 (3, 2): 7,
 (3, 3): 4,
 (3, 4): 2,
 (3, 5): 4}
```

I was hoping there was a simple function that could flatten my nested dictionary. I tried `FlatDict` function from [here](https://flatdict.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#example), but I wasn't sure how to modify this as I have a tuple in my dictionary.

Any suggestions on how to get the desired output?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? Where is your code? Please see [mcve], [ask], [help/on-topic]. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try with a  [`dict` Comprehension](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension):

```
dct={(1, 1): {'Transportation_Cost': 4},
 (1, 2): {'Transportation_Cost': 5},
 (1, 3): {'Transportation_Cost': 6},
 (1, 4): {'Transportation_Cost': 8},
 (1, 5): {'Transportation_Cost': 10},
 (2, 1): {'Transportation_Cost': 6},
 (2, 2): {'Transportation_Cost': 4},
 (2, 3): {'Transportation_Cost': 3},
 (2, 4): {'Transportation_Cost': 5},
 (2, 5): {'Transportation_Cost': 8},
 (3, 1): {'Transportation_Cost': 9},
 (3, 2): {'Transportation_Cost': 7},
 (3, 3): {'Transportation_Cost': 4},
 (3, 4): {'Transportation_Cost': 2},
 (3, 5): {'Transportation_Cost': 4}}

dct={k:v['Transportation_Cost'] for k,v in dct.items()}
print(dct)
```

Output:

```
{(1, 1): 4,
 (1, 2): 5,
 (1, 3): 6,
 (1, 4): 8,
 (1, 5): 10,
 (2, 1): 6,
 (2, 2): 4,
 (2, 3): 3,
 (2, 4): 5,
 (2, 5): 8,
 (3, 1): 9,
 (3, 2): 7,
 (3, 3): 4,
 (3, 4): 2,
 (3, 5): 4}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can use a `dict` comprehension:

```
d = {(1, 1): {'Transportation_Cost': 4},
     (1, 2): {'Transportation_Cost': 5},
     (1, 3): {'Transportation_Cost': 6},
     (1, 4): {'Transportation_Cost': 8},
     (1, 5): {'Transportation_Cost': 10},
     (2, 1): {'Transportation_Cost': 6},
     (2, 2): {'Transportation_Cost': 4},
     (2, 3): {'Transportation_Cost': 3},
     (2, 4): {'Transportation_Cost': 5},
     (2, 5): {'Transportation_Cost': 8},
     (3, 1): {'Transportation_Cost': 9},
     (3, 2): {'Transportation_Cost': 7},
     (3, 3): {'Transportation_Cost': 4},
     (3, 4): {'Transportation_Cost': 2},
     (3, 5): {'Transportation_Cost': 4}}

d = {k:d[k]['Transportation_Cost'] for k in d}

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{(1, 1): 4,
 (1, 2): 5,
 (1, 3): 6,
 (1, 4): 8,
 (1, 5): 10,
 (2, 1): 6,
 (2, 2): 4,
 (2, 3): 3,
 (2, 4): 5,
 (2, 5): 8,
 (3, 1): 9,
 (3, 2): 7,
 (3, 3): 4,
 (3, 4): 2,
 (3, 5): 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of editing your dictionary, you could create your dictionary from a Series object.

```
pd.Series(tc).to_dict()
```

Then you won't have to worry about the dictionary in a dictionary format.